# Centroid of the upper half of cardioid curve

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, contour-integration, curves

The cardioid is given by polar coordinates: $$C: r=\frac{1+\cos(\phi)}{2}, \quad \phi \in(0; \pi)$$

I established that the lenght of the curve is equal to $2$, but I'm having great difficulties with integrals:

$$\int_C x \, dC$$ and $$\int_C y \, dC$$

Do You have any suggestions regarding the solution, or better yet the solution itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cardioid is more natural in polar coordinates, we can directly measure the arc length in polar coordinates via
$$ds=\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}dr$$
as derived [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArcLength.aspx). So we have
$$\bar{x} \int_C dC = \int_C x  \ dC = \int_0^\pi r\cos(\theta)\sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}dr$$
This integral is fairly doable and WolframAlpha can help if you get stuck. The situation for $y$ is nearly identical.

Comment: Okay, sorry for Your inconvenience. It appears that I was given the wrong formula. Thanks!